# PHP mail() function not working in Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, postfix

I followed all the links [given in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450589/php-mail-using-sendmail-on-mac-os-x-leopard-10-5-8), nothing worked out.
Please explain me why PHP `mail()` does give so much problem? What exactly happening and why it will not work?

I am using macOS Lion (10.7.3).

I did all changes whatever is necessary like:

```
setting MAILSERVER=-YES- in my /etc/hostconfig
Setting sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i  in php.ini
Setting myhostname variable in /etc/postfix/main.cf 
Setting hostname/User/Pass in submit.cred
```

So please give me solution other than changing those files.

Problems I am facing are:

1. As soon as I start postfix, I will get warning messages

   ```
   sudo postfix start
   postfix/postfix-script: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/main.cf
   postfix/postfix-script: warning: not owned by root: /etc/postfix/submit.cred
   postfix/postfix-script: warning: not owned by _postfix:     /Library/Server/Mail/Data/mta/./master.lock
   postfix/postfix-script: warning: group or other writable: /Library/Server/Mail/Data/mta
   postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
   ```
2. In mail.log , I will get the following output:

   ```
   postfix/smtp[470]: 211B318690B: to=<test@example.com>, relay=none, delay=86583, delays=86521/0.05/62/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4002:c02::1a]:25: No route to host)
   postfix/smtp[473]: connect to test@example.com : Operation timed out
   postfix/smtp[473]: to=<test@example.com>, relay=none, delay=169837, delays=169717/0.04/120/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to example.com: Operation timed out)
   ```

When I ping to `alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`, it will say

```
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
36 bytes from IPADD: Communication prohibited by filter
```

(Note that `IPADD` means some IP address is given there.)

Comment: you've got a firewall preventing pings from reaching google, the postfix warnings are clear enough... it's not configured properly, you've got communications issues, etc... and this question is offtopic for this site, since it's server configuration problems, not actual programming issues.

Comment: Is your ISP filtering outbound port 25?

Comment: Ask your ISP what server you should send outbound mail to, and configure your server to relay to your ISP's server. Otherwise, you're going to have to administer a real Internet mail server, and that's a pretty huge undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

We just did that yesterday by simply following [this blog post](http://www.garron.me/mac/postfix-relay-gmail-mac-os-x-local-smtp.html). It configures your Mac to deliver eMails to Google mail.

All the links you were following simply activate the mail server, but if it is not configured properly, your mail orovider will not accept the email as it will be regarded as spam. So be careful! You might convert your Mac into a spam-machine!

Oh, and the warnings are simple warnings, so you should fix them, but you might also ignore them.

Comment: In addition to the answer given by @heiglandreas , make sure you chown the respective files as the warning messages tell you so. "Not owned by root"